# How to include large data into JsonGenerator as rawData while creating wrapper JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I have a Java application method which accepts `InputStream` as its input parameter. This input parameter includes the large customer data in JSON format. I have to create the wrapper elements to this JSON to match the standard.

The user provided JSON looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Batman",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "Gotham"
  },
  {
    "name": "Superman",
    "age": 33,
    "city": "Gotham"
  }
]
```

After creating the wrapper my JSON should look something like this (Expected Output):

```
{
  "type": "customerDocument",
  "creationDate": "2005-07-11T11:30:47.0Z",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "Gotham"
      },
      {
        "name": "Superman",
        "age": 33,
        "city": "Gotham"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am creating the same using following approach:

```
//Method to frame the outer wrapper elements for the JSON.
private InputStream generateJsonWrapper(final InputStream usersList) throws IOException {
    final JsonFactory jsonfactory = new JsonFactory();
    final StringWriter jsonObjectWriter = new StringWriter();
    final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonfactory.createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter);
    jsonfactory.createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter);
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", "customerDocument");
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("creationDate", Instant.now().toString());
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("customerBody");
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("customerList");
    jsonGenerator.writeRawValue(IOUtils.toString(usersList, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jsonGenerator.flush();
    jsonGenerator.close();
  return new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonObjectWriter.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

The above provided approach works fine and able to get the required JSON but here I need to convert the provided usersList to String and add it. Then finally the String need to be converted to InputStream.

Is there any approach using which I can avoid converting the `InputStream usersList` to String while adding `writeRaw`?